# Anime about a boy with black hair and a 10 foot tall grey robot

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching (on TV) an anime with a young boy (black hair) and a robot (all grey). The robot was not huge, like being able the pick the boy up in his hand. He was more like ten feet tall. And they were friends.

It is probably like 15 years old.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) and [edit] in anything else? For example, are there any memorable plot points?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot do you remember what TV channel you saw it on?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You probably didn't mean to ping me :)

Comment: no but it was on like a regular cartoon channel like cartoon network or something.

Comment: @PaulaFlache without some more details, this is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: nope not steam detectives the robot was tall and thin, the boy was more childlike/cute. I realize this is like a needle in a haystack but it is driving me crazy. It came up in a conversation about what type anime me and my friends like. Then this anime name just slipped out of my head for some reason sorry guys.

Answer (score 2):

It might be [***Steam Detectives***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_Detectives) (1998-99).

The anime centers around Narutaki, a boy detective with black hair, and his assistant, a nurse called Ling Ling. When in need, he can call upon a grey robot called Goriki, invented by Ling Ling's father. It seems to be the only robot capable of independent thought; the rest are remote-controlled. The setting is Steam City, a sort of steampunky 1950s France.

Here is a picture from the show, showing the main characters:

[image: Steam Detectives main characters]